# Working with EF4 and MySql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-4

Need some advice working with EF4 and MySql.

I have a table with lots of data items. Each item belongs to a module and a zone. The data item also has a timestamp (ticks). The most common usage is for the app to query for data after a specified time for a module and a zone. The data should be sorted.

Problem is that the query selects to many rows and the database server will be low on memory resulting in a very slow query. I tried to limit the query to 100 items but the generated sql will only apply the limit after all the items has been selected and sorted.

> ```
> dataRepository.GetData().WithModuleId(ModuleId).InZone(ZoneId).After(ztime).OrderBy(p
> ```
>
> => p.Timestamp).Take(100).ToList();

Generated SQL by the MySql .Net Connector 6.3.6

```
 SELECT  
`Project1`.`Id`,  
`Project1`.`Data`,  
`Project1`.`Timestamp`,  
`Project1`.`ModuleId`,  
`Project1`.`ZoneId`,  
`Project1`.`Version`,  
`Project1`.`Type`  
FROM (SELECT  
`Extent1`.`Id`,  
`Extent1`.`Data`,  
`Extent1`.`Timestamp`,  
`Extent1`.`ModuleId`,  
`Extent1`.`ZoneId`,  
`Extent1`.`Version`,  
`Extent1`.`Type`  
FROM `DataItems` AS `Extent1`  
 WHERE ((`Extent1`.`ModuleId` = 1) AND (`Extent1`.`ZoneId` = 1)) AND  
(`Extent1`.`Timestamp` > 634376753657189002)) AS `Project1`  
 ORDER BY  
`Timestamp` ASC LIMIT 100
```

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE  `mydb`.`DataItems` (

  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `Data` mediumblob NOT NULL,  
  `Timestamp` bigint(20) NOT NULL,  
  `ModuleId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,  
  `ZoneId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,  
  `Version` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  `Type` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),  
  KEY `IX_FK_ModuleDataItem` (`ModuleId`),  
  KEY `IX_FK_ZoneDataItem` (`ZoneId`),  
  KEY `Index_4` (`Timestamp`),  
  KEY `Index_5` (`ModuleId`,`ZoneId`),  
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ModuleDataItem` FOREIGN KEY (`ModuleId`) REFERENCES  
`Modules` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,  
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ZoneDataItem` FOREIGN KEY (`ZoneId`) REFERENCES `Zones`  
(`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22904 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

All suggestions on how to solve this are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

What's your GetData() method doing?  I'd bet it's executing a query on the entire table.  And that's why your Take(100) at the end isn't doing anything.

Comment: The GetData returns an IQueryable, the actual generated SQL query is described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the Table Splitting method described here:
[Table splitting in entity framework](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/10/13/table-splitting-in-entity-framework.aspx)